# Rails SQlite3 ActiveRecord select then update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite, transactions

I have a table where I need to select some row and update it based on a previous value, or create it if does not exist, and I need this to be safe if multiple HTTP requests are made at once regarding the same row/record.

I tried using a transaction and ActiveRecord.lock but it results in "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked" whenever there are multiple requests. My intention was that the second request would just wait/block on the select statement and that active record would use the facilities available in the DB to do so in the most efficient manner (e.g. row locking if available, etc.).

```
MyModel.transaction
  record = MyModel.lock.find_by(name: update_name) #name is a unique index in the SQL table
  if record
    # The actual manipulation is more complex than something I want to do directly in a SQL statement
    record.update!(value: record.value + add_value)
  else
    record.create(name: update_name, value: add_value)
  end
end
```

Currently using Rails 5 with Ruby 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

This is a database problem you would need to do two things:

Make your `name` unique in your database, if you haven't yet, so the database fails if you try to save a new record with the same `name`, you will need to handle the error accordingly: tell the user it failed, the name is already selected and whatnot.

For creating or updating you can use:

```
MyModel.find_or_create_by(name: update_name) do |record|
  record.value += add_value
  record.save
end
```

But again, that method above is not atomic, that's why you have to wrap everything around a `rescue` and handle the error accordingly.

Comment: I said the column is a unique index in the db, so not breaking that is fine, if i really have to manually handle the constraint exception I can, but would rather an automated solution. But a race between a select and an update will effectivly corrupt my data (the last update "wins" but the value it stored is wrong), and there will be no unique index violation there, and so no exception/warning to rescue?